# MainMenu.xib not found after base localization was disabled in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm working on a Mac OS application that should be supported on 10.7. The project was created under Xcode 5 running on Mavericks with base localization initially enabled.

I've now removed base localization so that I can support 10.7 but have been unable to get the application to run at all anymore, either on 10.7 or 10.9 because Xcode generates the following error:

`Unable to load nib file: MainMenu.xib, exiting`

So I added a new MainMenu.xib file via `File - New File - MainMenu`. I wired up the AppDelegate object and set the delegates.

Back in the project file, I made sure of the following:

- MainMenu.xib is part of the build target's `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase.
- Made sure that `MainMenu.xib` is selected in the targets `General - Main Interface` setting
- Checked in the `File Inspector` for `MainMenu.xib` and saw that it was localized into `English` and that a checkmark was checked beside that.

I can't think of what else should be set. I've even created a new, empty project for testing. With that, I made no changes other than to delete the base localization and then attempt to re-add a new MainMenu.xib and follow the steps outlined above, but to no avail. That build fails as well when launching in Xcode with the same error.

I've even tried using a different XIB file with a different name (yet still one setup as a MainMenu) but all that did was change the error message to reflect the new XIB name I had specified in the settings.

While I'm sure base localization is great, I'm hoping to support 10.7 users so I don't believe that keeping base localization enabled is an option for me.

Any help (even if it's pointing out the obvious) would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your Apps Info.plist file (or Info settings in Xcode), what's the value of the `Localization native development region`?   This should be your native language.  Also, what's the file layout of your XIBs right now?  Is your MainMenu.xib in the base `Resources` folder or in an `.lproj` folder?

Comment: @gaige: The `Localization Native Development Region` is set to `en`, which sounds right to me. My `MainMenu.xib` file is located in the `en.lproj` folder, the few other XIB files I use are located one directory higher (where Xcode defaults to putting all your source files). I do not have a folder called `Resources`. Using the file inspector in Xcode, I've checked that my project is correctly referencing that `MainMenu.xib` file. Still at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally found the culprit. When the `base` localization was deleted, a new `MainMenu` XIB file needed to be created and selected in the target. Under `Targets - Deployment Info - Main Interface` the drop-down menu lists all available XIB files in the project that you could specify as the `Main Interface`. Naturally, I selected my newly created `MainMenu.xib` file and that's where the problems started.

After diff'ing the changes that Xcode had made to the `Project Settings` file, I noticed that in the working copy, the `Main Interface` key was set to `MainMenu` whereas in the non-working copy the key was set to `MainMenu.xib`, which is precisely what was in the drop-down menu.

Manually removing the `.xib` extension from the `Targets - Deployment Info - Main Interface` combo-box appears to have things working again. Note that it was the combo box in the first place that added the `.xib` suffix.

There might be more at play here, but that simple change has resulted in the program now properly launching.